# Creating a Graphical Interface for Tic Tac Toe in C++

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d-games

I have created a Tic Tac Toe program in C++ playable against the computer. At present my interface is something like you have to chose a number from 1-9 which corresponds to the location you can make your turn on. I want to change this to a clickable graphic interface. What are my options to do these? Some tutorial links would be extremely helpful. I'm using windows 7

Comment: Does it have to be in C++?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I would prefer it since I also want to know how graphics are implemented in C++

Comment: You don't say what OS. [Here's a MS tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Qt for implementing Graphical User Interfaces in C++.

See more here: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-declarative-toys-tic-tac-toe-example.html

Comment: Qt is great for cross-platform development. I've used it for Mac OSX, Windows XP/Windows 7, and Linux with almost no trouble porting between them (OSX was a bit of a learning curve). I've used a number of GUI toolkits, and it's by far the easiest to get great looking interfaces up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

what compiler/IDE you are using.if it is visual studio then you beter go for native C/C++ APIs provided by windows you can get help to find th APIs at msdn.microsoft.com or even you can install MSDN on your machine.its better to start with native APIs rather than starting with qt on windows you may face many troubles installing qt.